# Netbeans Project Not deployed

Tags: netbeans, authorization, tomcat7

```
C:\Users\Anand\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LoginServer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1033:     Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username   and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

All is set to execute the Code. Clean and Build Done,when i'm executing the code it throws the above error though the tomcat server is running well. I cant authorise the tomcat. How can i do this???
Help..!!

Comment: "See the server log for details." I would start there.

Comment: @ElGavilan Which log u would start with Tomcat Log or IDE Log??